# Having trouble with voice command to navigate to contact address

Tags: voice-command, google-maps-navigation

When I select a contact, then select its address, Maps opens. Then I can navigate to it with the Google navigation app.

However, if I try doing this *directly* with the system-wide speech input, this is not working. The input is interpreted correctly (correct contact and Google navigation opens), but then the address of the contact is not found.

Comment: What command are you giving? I use "navigate to john doe home" and haven't noticed a problem. We probably need to know the version of Android and the device.

Comment: The command I use should be correct (it's German though). The contact is understood right and the navigation app opens as intended. I'm using 4.0.3 on a Nexus S.

Comment: The German command is "Ilse Müller ansteuern". Because of different grammar, the syntax is different in comparison to English.